# Book with two timelines and two girls. The book specifically says that timelines are tangled

Tags: story-identification, novel, timeline

So, there are two girls; one of them is living in present day and does some kind of research with a drug and kinda 'dies', but she gets this out of body experience. In the other timeline, there's a girl who's living in the stone age or something and hunts for a living. Then there is this villain who's like very handsome and deadly and the girls together try to defeat him but they couldn't. There's a sequel to it because the story doesn't end in the first book. The main thing is that the book specifically says that timelines are tangled and sometimes they do overlap each other.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

Answer (score 5):

Is this ***[Entangled](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7857727-entangled)*** (2010) by Graham Hancock...?

According to the Goodreads synopsis, a teenage girl from the 21st century has a near-death experience as the result of a drug overdose, causing her soul to travel 24,000 years back in time, where she teams up with a young Stone Age woman against a demon who wishes to enslave humanity.

> **When a drug overdose causes Leoni, a troubled teen from twenty-first-century Los Angeles, to have a near-death experience, her soul is lifted from the modern world and flung into a parallel time 24,000 years in the past. There her fate becomes entangled with that of Ria, a young Stone Age woman fighting for her life against the ferocious Illimani, an army of evil led by the vicious Sulpa, a powerful demon determined to destroy humanity.As the invaders annihilate Ria's people, inflicting torture and human sacrifice, Sulpa moves ever closer to his ultimate goal: to manifest physically in the twenty-first century and condemn all of mankind to perpetual slavery.** The hour is late and any chance of stopping him seems lost. But there is still hope, if Leoni and Ria can rise to the challenge fate has set them. Uniting outside the flow of earth time, they must venture forth into regions of wonder, master their own deepest fears, and fight battles they could never have prepared for, if Sulpa is to be defeated...
>
> [image: Front cover of "Entangled" (2010) by Graham Hancock.]

The following excerpt, pulled from the [Google Books preview of the book itself](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Entangled/G_4zpbX243YC?hl=en&gbpv=0), mentions the two timelines overlapping and becoming entangled.

> A flicker caught Leoni's eye and she glanced down at the screen.
> **The green timeline was back.**
> The Angel once again pointed to the place where **the twenty-first century intersected with the Stone Age.** "You will note," she said, "that the knot here is very dense and this intersection is also surrounded by other superimposed epochs..."
> Leoni looked. **She could see many points that would have been widely separated if the Angel had simply drawn a straight line across the screen, but that lay close together and frequently overlapped in this intertwined and knotted line.**
>
> [...]
>
> The Angel's finger touched the screen again: "Because **time is so densely entangled in this region,** many other epochs lie closely superimposed. [...]"